# Is it possible to use HTTP Basic Auth with form data in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi

I have several FastAPI methods which should be protected by HTTP basic auth. I have followed the docs, but can't seem to get it to work properly. In swagger, the lock icon is shown in the upper right, but whether there are creds or not, the method is executed. Likewise, no pop-up for auth is observed. When I create a basic scenario using path parameters, it works,  but these methods use form data. What am I missing?

```
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

security = HTTPBasic()

def check_credentials(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)) -> None:
    """Validate user credentials

    Args:
        HTTP Basic Auth credentials

    Raises:
        HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized
    """
    username = bytes(config_params['API_USER'],encoding='utf8')
    password = bytes(config_params['API_PASS'],encoding='utf8')
    input_uname = credentials.username.encode('utf8')
    input_pass = credentials.password.encode('utf8')
    valid_uname = secrets.compare_digest(input_uname, username)
    valid_pass = secrets.compare_digest(input_pass, password)
    if not valid_uname:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    if not valid_pass:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )


@app.post('/commit')
def commit_configuration(
    device: str = Form(),
    insecure: bool = Form(),
    credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(check_credentials)
):
```

Comment: Have you verified that `check_credentials` gets called as you expect, and that you're actually raising an exception?

Comment: @MatsLindh I don't see any indication of it being called, but there is definitely no exception thrown.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like it works with cURL, but not using the Swagger UI

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I posted a bit too soon... The browser was saving the credentials. For anyone that runs into this, using Swagger in Incognito should provide good tests.